# Displaying data in salesforce app from outside

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

Hi I am very new to Salesforce, the below is what I am trying to achieve.

I am using a machine learning algorithm in Python, and result of this needs to be displayed in salesforce app.

Currently this data to be displayed resides in a place in a different server.

Is it possible to display data not residing in salesforce in salesforce app (Without creating new fields in salesforce) ?

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any interactions of your Python app with Salesforce logic, you can integrate an with the Salesforce UI using [Force.com Canvas](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Canvas).

But if data from Python app should to be processed by some logic in SF, I think you need to use Salesforce API for integration. But it's way which you want to avoid.